# How to Have Two Different Object Methods Use Each Other as Paramters

Tags: c++, class

header.h

```
class Foo{
public:
void fooFunction(std::map <std::string, Bar> &);
}

class Bar{
public:
void barFunction(std::map <std::string, Foo> &, Foo &);
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get an error saying Bar is not declared in the scope of fooFunction, and when I switch the order of the declarations, I get an error saying Foo is not in the scope of barFunction.

How can I make them be in the scope of each other? If I need multiple header files, how should I set that up in my makefile and #include s?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply forward-declare the other class in the header that requires it:

```
class Bar;

class Foo
{
public:
    void fooFunction(std::map <std::string, Bar>&);
};

class Bar
{
public:
    void barFunction(std::map<std::string, Foo>&, Foo &);
};
```

This works provided that `Foo` does not use `Bar` *by value* anywhere until after `Bar` has been defined.  That means storing it as a member, passing as parameter, returning value of that type.  In this case you're fine, since the `Foo` parameters are passed by reference.

Note that even though your `std::map` stores type `Bar` by value, this is still okay because it's a template and is not resolved until you use it, at which time `Bar` will be defined.

Comment: You could declare it right where it's used  (`std::map<std::string, class Bar>&`) but it's probably clearer how you have it.